# Harmonizing variables across countries

Tags: survey, survey-weights

Say, I have run an experiment in 2 separate countries, the U.S. and Tchad. While the outcome was isomorphically measured in both settings, one key background variable was not. Specifically, income was measured in different currencies. I now wonder whether I should "harmonize" the data across the two countries (e.g., using exchange rates or some PPP method). Since the two countries have highly different income levels, it doesn't feel right to do that. My preferred approach would be to analyze the experiments in both countries separately, and to do one joint model with fixed effects for both countries. That should maintain the explanatory power of the income variables, rather than forcing them on one unified scale. I'd greatly appreciate feedback on my reasoning.

Comment: You should think about if, for your purpose (your response variable) it is "absolute poverty" or "relative poverty" which is important!

Answer (score 0):

PPPs are designed to make variables like income comparable, so I would apply that. Applying a PPP for two countries in a single year is just a linear transformation, so you won't loose any explanatory power when applying that. However, it does make sense to me to try to add an interaction effect between country and income, which will allow the variable income to have a different effect in Chad and the US. Doing your analyses separately for both countries is a crude way of doing that. I would prefer a single model with interactions, as that way I can actually test the differences in effects. Only adding a fixed effect for country won't allow the effect of income to differ across countries, so that would not be my choice.